# Does the QNAP NAS boxes support combining multiple devices into one volume?

Tags: networking, raid, nas, storage

[image: QNAP TS-419P+ Turbo 4-bay NAS]

I'm thinking about buying a [QNAP TS-419P+ Turbo 4-bay NAS](http://www.qnap.com/pro_detail_feature.asp?p_id=183). The problem is it's not very scalable. If I've inserted 4 disks and filled all the space, there's no way of expanding (Other than buying new disks in a larger size). Is there any hope in buying one of these now, then perhaps buying another one later and combining the two into one volume?

If the QNAP can't do this, is there another device that can?

Comment: We have exactly the same model in our office, it'd be great if there was something to allow this. But maybe we should make the question more general (i.e. "Is there a way to combine multiple NAS devices into one volume?") so that it's not limited to one specific QNAP box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A product that explicitly supports adding extra enclosures is the [Synology DS1511+](http://www.synology.com/enu/products/DS1511+/index.php). Up to two additional DX510 enclosures can be connected (via eSATA) for a maximum of 15 drives.

The other option is to buy an enclosure with more than 4-5 drive bays, and add drives in the future when needed. If you need disk redundancy, rather than [JBOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-RAID_drive_architectures#JBOD), then you may need either a Synology NAS enclosure with "Synology Hybrid RAID" or the Drobo equivalent called "BeyondRAID". These technologies allow you to add drives, of any size, at any time. I don't think any QNAS devices have this feature.

Comment: +1 for the great suggestion! I'm going to keep this unaccepted for a while in case a better one comes along though :)